# Wordpress plugins Install/Update timeout

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, plugins, timeout

I have been installing/updating my self-hosted Wordpress themes/plugins through FTP. ie get the link from my wordpress site, go download the plugin from wordpress.org, upload from my comp to the site through FTP.

I want to be able to update it through the wp admin interface instead, but it seems to timeout and the page just stops loading after a while. I can see half the files uploaded successfully through FTP. Is there a way around this?

Here is an example of what is shown on the screen:

> Installing Theme: DMS 1.0.3.6 Downloading install package from
>   https://wordpress.org/themes/download/dms.1.0.3.6.zip…
>
> Unpacking the package…
>
> Installing the theme…

1) I have added the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT in wp-config.php file with

> define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '100M');

Nothing happens.

2) I have added set_time_limit() to wp-config.php file

```
set_time_limit()
```

and this error occured

> Warning: set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in
>   /home/********/public_html/wp-config.php on line 83

3) I tried editing the .htaccess file, but that breaks the whole workpress installation and I end up seeing an error page instead.

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M 
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value memory_limit 100M
```

How can I install/update my plugins directly through the Wordpress User Interface? Is there a way around the timeout?

My webhost is www.000webhost.com btw.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up editing the `...\wp_includes\class-http.php` file.

Around line 1250 (depending on your version), look for the line that reads:

`$theResponse = curl_exec( $handle );`

and change it to read:

```
$timelimit = ini_get('max_execution_time');
set_time_limit(900);
$theResponse = curl_exec( $handle );
set_time_limit(max($timelimit, 30));
```

This stores the current timeout in a variable, sets the new timeout to 900 seconds (5 minutes should be plenty for most connections), then it performs the request, and resets the timeout to what ever it was before we began.

That has worked for me in the past.
NB: v3.8.2 uses another asynchronous method to perform installs and if you're on windows, you might need to set some additional security permissions etc. to get it all working properly.

Cheers.

Comment: There is no such line in `class-http.php`

Comment: erm... no... but back in 2014 there was.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes updating plugins can 'break' your site, the only way to fix is to go back to your ftp folder and disable the plugins - (rename the folder temporarily ought to do it) - then when you can see your site again, try enabling the folder again and activating your plugins one by one,

Comment: Hi Andi, I am not having a problem with plugins. More about updating the plugins through the wordpress UI. I currently update them manually by dowloading the whole zip folder and reuploading the whole thing through FTP. Is it possible to overcome the timeout problem, so wordpress can update through the UI?

Comment: all i know is that its happened to me a few times and it kind of 'breaks' the site - ive tried updating one by one and that helps, but sometimes ive had to go in and delete the hidden .maintenance file too. - are the plugins unusually large?

Answer (score 0):

If someone desires to bypass WP Update Check Timeout use this (add inside init hook):

```
delete_site_transient( 'update_plugins' );
wp_cache_delete( 'plugins', 'plugins' );
```

After use, you can remove of course.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Add to **wp-config.php**:

```
set_time_limit(300);
```